# SQL NOT EXISTS (Person hates everybody they know) EDITED

Tags: sql

So I have these three tables

```
Persons {id, name}
    {1, "Jim"}
    {2, "Kim"}
    {3, "Tim"}
    {4, "Brim"}
Knows {id_A, id_B}
    {1,2}
    {1,3}
    {1,4}
    {2,3}
    {4,2}
Hates {id_A, id_B}
    {1,4}
    {2,1}
    {3,1}
    {3,2}
    {4,2}
```

And I want to get data using NOT EXIST to get names of all Persons who hates everyone they know. I tried this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.name FROM Persons P, Likes L, Knows K
WHERE K.personA_id = P.id AND L.personA_id = P.id
AND NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM Persons P WHERE L.personA_id = P.id AND L.personB_id <>  K.personB_id)
```

but it also returns name if a person knows several people but hate at least one of them (For example this query returns {1, "Jim"} even he knows 3 people but only hates 1 of them). And I need to get person who hates EVERYONE they know.. Help!

Comment: Show sample data please.

Comment: Is likes the same as knows? If not, where are likes stored?

Comment: I wouldn't use `not exist` for this.  Why is that a requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Written another way, give me all people that knows someone they do not hate:

```
SELECT * FROM Persons p
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 0 FROM Knows k
    WHERE k.personA_id = P.id
    AND NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 0 FROM Hates h
        WHERE k.personA_id = h.personA_id
    )
)
```

Comment: with some little changes this solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you are not using the other tables in sub-query. You should do somthing like this:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.name FROM Persons P, Hates H, Knows K
WHERE K.A_id = P.id AND H.A_id = P.id
AND NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM Persons P, Hates H, Knows K WHERE H.A_id = P.id and H.B_id <> K.B_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't like NOT EXISTS but this is a possible solution for "person who hates EVERYONE they know"

```
SELECT P.name FROM Persons p
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
    -- person who knows persons and doesn't hate them
  SELECT * FROM Knows k
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Hates h
   ON (h.id_B = k.id_B and h.id_A = k.id_A)
    WHERE p.id = k.id_A -- join Person
    AND  k.id_B is null
)
```